# Network authentication

Tags: java

Am having difficulty connection to a server using java code, I get 401 error, but with the same username and password an able to connect using the browser

Below is my code:

```
public class NTLMAuthentication
{
    static final String kuser = "username"; 
    static final String kpass = "password"; 

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

        URL url = new URL("http://[portNumber]:7047/DynamicsNAV110/WS/CED%20RATED%20LTD%20/Page/SalesInvoice");

        InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String str;
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: That `http://[portNumber]:7047` looks wrong, or is `[portNumber]` not a real number, but a domain name instead?

Comment: Its just because I dont want to reveal the real port number

Comment: You already did, it's 7047.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the IP Address, should rather be URL url = new URL("http://IP_Address:7047/DynamicsNAV110/WS/CED%20RATED%20LTD%20/Page/SalesInvoice");